# Trying to control 8x8 led matrix with raspberry pi without max7219

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

At this time I dont have max7219 chip so I'm trying to control an 8x8 dot-matrix display with my raspberry without it, so I found this code but it gives me IndentationError on line 75, I'm pretty noob at python, how can I solve this?
Thanks for the help.

Should I erase all comments?

```
#working
import RPi.GPIO as IO  #calling for header file which helps in using GPIO’s of PI
import time            #calling for time to provide delays in program
IO.setwarnings(False)  #do not show any warnings
x=1
y=1
IO.setmode (IO.BCM)  #programming the GPIO by BCM pin numbers. (like PIN29 as'GPIO5')
IO.setup(12,IO.OUT)  #initialize GPIO12 as an output.
IO.setup(22,IO.OUT)  #initialize GPIO22 as an output.
IO.setup(27,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(25,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(17,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(24,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(23,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(18,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(21,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(20,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(26,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(16,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(19,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(13,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(6,IO.OUT)
IO.setup(5,IO.OUT)

PORTVALUE = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]
#value of pin in each port 
A=[0,0b01111111,0b11111111,0b11001100,0b11001100,0b11001100,0b11111111,0b01111111]
B =[0,0b00111100,0b01111110,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11111111,0b11111111]
C= [0,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11100111,0b01111110,0b00111100]
D=[0,0b01111110,0b10111101,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11111111,0b11111111]
E=[0,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11111111,0b11111111]
F=[0,0b11011000,0b11011000,0b11011000,0b11011000,0b11011000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
G=[0b00011111,0b11011111,0b11011000,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11111111,0b11111111]
H=[0,0b11111111,0b11111111,0b00011000,0b00011000,0b00011000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
I=[0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11111111,0b11111111,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011]
J=[0b11000000,0b11000000,0b11000000,0b11111111,0b11111111,0b11000011,0b11001111,0b11001111]
K=[0,0b11000011,0b11100111,0b01111110,0b00111100,0b00011000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
L=[0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b11111111,0b11111111]
M=[0b11111111,0b11111111,0b01100000,0b01110000,0b01110000,0b01100000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
N=[0b11111111,0b11111111,0b00011100,0b00111000,0b01110000,0b11100000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
O=[0b01111110,0b11111111,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11000011,0b11111111,0b01111110]
P=[0,0b01110000,0b11111000,0b11001100,0b11001100,0b11001100,0b11111111,0b11111111]
Q=[0b01111110,0b11111111,0b11001111,0b11011111,0b11011011,0b11000011,0b11111111,0b01111110]
R=[0b01111001,0b11111011,0b11011111,0b11011110,0b11011100,0b11011000,0b11111111,0b11111111]
S=[0b11001110,0b11011111,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11011011,0b11111011,0b01110011]
T=[0b11000000,0b11000000,0b11000000,0b11111111,0b11111111,0b11000000,0b11000000,0b11000000]
U=[0b11111110,0b11111111,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b11111111,0b11111110]
V=[0b11100000,0b11111100,0b00011110,0b00000011,0b00000011,0b00011110,0b11111100,0b11100000]
W=[0b11111110,0b11111111,0b00000011,0b11111111,0b11111111,0b00000011,0b11111111,0b11111110]
X=[0b01000010,0b11100111,0b01111110,0b00111100,0b00111100,0b01111110,0b11100111,0b01000010]
Y=[0b01000000,0b11100000,0b01110000,0b00111111,0b00111111,0b01110000,0b11100000,0b01000000]
Z=[0b11000011,0b11100011,0b11110011,0b11111011,0b11011111,0b11001111,0b11000111,0b11000011]

def PORT(pin):  #assigning GPIO state by taking 'pin' value
    if(pin&0x01 == 0x01):
        IO.output(21,0)   #if bit0 of 8bit 'pin' is true pull PIN21 low
    else:
        IO.output(21,1)   #if bit0 of 8bit 'pin' is false pull PIN21 high
    if(pin&0x02 == 0x02):
        IO.output(20,0)   #if bit1 of 8bit 'pin' is true pull PIN20 low
    else:
        IO.output(20,1)   #if bit1 of 8bit 'pin' is false pull PIN20 high
    if(pin&0x04 == 0x04):
        IO.output(26,0)   #if bit2 of 8bit 'pin' is true pull PIN26 low
    else:
        IO.output(26,1)   #if bit2 of 8bit 'pin' is false pull PIN26 high
    if(pin&0x08 == 0x08):
        IO.output(16,0)
    else:
        IO.output(16,1)

if(pin&0x10 == 0x10):
        IO.output(19,0)
    else:
        IO.output(19,1)
    if(pin&0x20 == 0x20):
        IO.output(13,0)
    else:
        IO.output(13,1)
    if(pin&0x40 == 0x40):
        IO.output(6,0)
    else:
        IO.output(6,1)
    if(pin&0x80 == 0x80):
        IO.output(5,0)
    else:
        IO.output(5,1)

def PORTP(pinp):    #assigning GPIO logic for positive terminals by taking 'pinp' value
    if(pinp&0x01 == 0x01): 
        IO.output(12,1)     #if bit0 of 8bit 'pinp' is true pull PIN12 high
    else:
        IO.output(12,0)     #if bit0 of 8bit 'pinp' is false pull PIN12 low
    if(pinp&0x02 == 0x02):
        IO.output(22,1)     #if bit1 of 8bit 'pinp' is true pull PIN22 high
    else:
        IO.output(22,0)     #if bit1 of 8bit 'pinp' is false pull PIN22 low
    if(pinp&0x04 == 0x04):
        IO.output(27,1)     #if bit2 of 8bit 'pinp' is true pull PIN27 high
    else:
        IO.output(27,0)     #if bit2 of 8bit 'pinp' is false pull PIN27 low
    if(pinp&0x08 == 0x08):
        IO.output(25,1)
    else:
        IO.output(25,0)
    if(pinp&0x10 == 0x10):
        IO.output(17,1)
    else:
        IO.output(17,0)
    if(pinp&0x20 == 0x20):
        IO.output(24,1)
    else:
        IO.output(24,0)
    if(pinp&0x40 == 0x40):
        IO.output(23,1)
    else:
        IO.output(23,0)
    if(pinp&0x80 == 0x80):
        IO.output(18,1) #if bit7 of 8bit 'pinp' is true pull PIN18 high
    else:
        IO.output(18,0) #if bit7 of 8bit 'pinp' is false pull PIN18 low

while 1:
    for y in range (100):   #execute loop 100 times
        for x in range (8): #execute the loop 8 times incrementing x value from zero to seven
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]  #assigning value to 'pin' for each digit
            PORT(pin);  #mapping appropriate GPIO 
            pinp= C[x]  #assigning character 'C' value to 'pinp' 
            PORTP(pinp); #turning the GPIO to show character 'C'
            time.sleep(0.0005) #wait for 0.5msec

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= I[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= R[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= C[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= U[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= I[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= T[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= D[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= I[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= G[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= E[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= S[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    for y in range (100):
        for x in range (8):
            pin  = PORTVALUE[x]
            PORT(pin);
            pinp= T[x]
            PORTP(pinp);
            time.sleep(0.0005)

    pinp= 0
    PORTP(pinp);
    time.sleep(1)
```

I added utf-8 encoding also.

Comment: "so I found this code but it gives me IndentationError on line 75, I'm pretty noob at python, how can I solve this?" Since the error message says the problem is on line 75, did you try looking at line 75? Since it says there is an `IndentationError`, did you try looking at how the line is indented? Specifically, did you try comparing it to the surrounding code to see if it makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(pin&0x10 == 0x10):
        IO.output(19,0)
    else:
        IO.output(19,1)
```

is not valid Python indentation.  The `if` and `else` have to be at the same indentation level.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for a quick intro to if/else statements.